# Why would one crash log symbolicate and not another?

Tags: cocoa-touch, crash, ios, segmentation-fault, sigabrt

I have two crash logs from a iPhone application in XCode Organizer. Both occurred within 20 minutes of each other, on the same device, running the same build of the application. While one has been symbolicated the other has not.

The unsymbolicated log has type and codes:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x00000000, 0x00000000
```

Whereas the symbolicated log has type and codes:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x61656810
```

Is this enough information to explain why the latter symbolicated correctly but the former not?

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced this too, and found that if you rename the crash log file and then drag and drop it into Xcode organizer, it will often symbolicate correctly.